# extjs: How to persist the state of an application

Tags: extjs

Let's say I have a panel/window containing a search form and tab(s) containing the search results.

Ideally the entered search values and the grid would be in the same state (e.g. sorted) when the user reloads the page.

I've seen the providers (cookie and local storage), but I am not sure how to go about it.

Do I have to wire every single control to the stateManager? Or is there a global way of persisting "everything"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe state manager will write only position, size etc. But if you need to save content of textboxes, database filters - I'm afraid you will have to write something yourself.